# VC++ Crashes when Compiling

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This is probably not the right place to put this, but I have no where else to go.

Every single time I press F7, it crashes. If I change the code, then press F5, it crashes. Every time I compile anything, it will crash. BUT, sometimes it succeeds, because after it crashes I can reload VC++ and I do not have to recompile. It is mainly just an extreme annoyance when debugging.

I tried to debug it, and it causes this issue:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0.dll
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider'.
This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

I tried to de-register then re-register ieproxy.dll and actxpxy.dll through cmd prompt, but nothing works. I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling Visual Studio?

Comment: I have tried that, several times with every version of VC++. I don't think the IServiceProvider COM is registered at all for some reason. Trying to figure out how to fix that.

Comment: Just use the compiler without the IDE?

Comment: Or IDE without compiler...

Comment: You didn't wrote which version of VS crashes, but: VisualStudio 2008 had a similar bug - if You messed a bit with windows layout inside VS, then crashes occurred when compiling or debugging. To fix it try to use "Reset Window Layout" from "Window" menu. Hope this helps.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bug report. You should report this to MS.

Comment: @rubenvb Tried, MS charges $259 to ask for support -_-

Comment: @baderman THANK YOU! Such a simple fix!!! Btw, I didn't put the version because any version I tried all had the same problem so it was irrelevant. Post an answer and I'll mark it as correct :)

Comment: @baderman Wait nvm its back at it. Now it builds the first time, and any other time it crashes. -_- Ughhhhh

Comment: @NicholasPipitone It does... I know. MS made an [hotfix](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB960075) for this, but then - the hotfix broke some other things in ide (intelisense for XAML, others?). Well, I've learned to live with that and now I've got few (2-3 max?) crashes a day. Used to have tons of them.  When having some windows left out (for me: output,find,find symbol, etc), first time I have to run normally (ctrl+f5), and after that I can use debug (F5/F10/F11) as long as I want. After session - save all, reset window position, and then I can close VS. Hope this'll help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall Internet Explorer 10, reinstall Internet Explorer 9, then uninstall the updates to Internet Explorer 9. Now re-register ieproxy.dll and it will work.